# Ruby 2 & Rails 4 Query returns results in development, but return nil in production

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

We are writing an application in ruby on rails and we are experiencing an oddity.
When we run the app in development our query returns just fine.
When we run the app in production our query returns nil, even with records in the database. I have queried directly through MySQL Server so I know the records are there.

Any Ideas? I have included the error, migration, model, controller and view code.

The error I get is

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Extracted source (around line #19):

```
          @count = 1
          if @leadsHot != nil || @leadsHot != ''
          @leadsHot.each do |lead| %>
          <tr role="row" <% if @count / @count == 0 %>class="gradeA even"<% else %> class="gradeA odd" <% end %>>
          <td class="sorting_1"><%= lead.category.to_s %></td>
          <td><%= lead.fname.to_s %> <%= lead.l_name.to_s %></td>
```

Migration File

```
  class CreateLeads < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :leads do |t|
      t.column :category, :string
      t.column :patent_status, :string
      t.column :over_eighteen, :string
      t.column :salute, :string
      t.column :fname, :string
      t.column :m_initial, :string
      t.column :l_name, :string
      t.column :address, :string
      t.column :address1, :string
      t.column :city, :string
      t.column :state, :string
      t.column :zip,:string
      t.column :phone, :string
      t.column :cell_phone, :string
      t.column :fax, :string
      t.column :email, :string
      t.column :user_id, :integer
      t.column :source, :string
      t.column :lead_source_id, :integer
      t.column :hot, :boolean, :null => false, :default => 0
      t.column :comments, :text
      t.column :active, :boolean
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :leads
  end
end
```

Model

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :lead_source
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :lead_source

    has_many :lead_contact_logs
  end
```

Controller

```
class Backoffice::SalesController < ApplicationController
  include LogIt
  include LeadManagement
  include SalesModule
  include TableDataMethods
  def dashboard
    @leadsAll = Lead.all().where("hot=0 AND active=1") #getvalidleads
    @leadsHot = Lead.all().where("hot=1 AND active=1")  #getHotLeads
    @leadsDOA = Lead.all().where("active=0") #getRecentDeadLeads
    @curClients = basicCurrentClientsTable
    if @curClients == nil
      @curClients = "<tr><td colspan='7'>No Clients Available</td></tr>"
    end
    if @leadsHot == nil
      @leadsHot = "<tr><td colspan='7'>No Hot Leads Available</td></tr>"
    end
  end
end
```

View

```
<div class="panel-body" style="display: none;">

    <table aria-describedby="data-table_info" role="grid" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" id="hotLeads">
      <thead>
      <tr role="row">
        <th aria-label="Lead Category: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="data-table" tabindex="0" class="sorting_asc">
          Lead Category
        </th>
        <th aria-label="Contact Name: activate to sort column ascending" style="" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="data-table" tabindex="0" class="sorting">Contact Name</th>
        <th aria-label="Phone: activate to sort column ascending" style="" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="data-table" tabindex="0" class="sorting">Phone</th>
        <th aria-label="Email: activate to sort column ascending" style="" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="data-table" tabindex="0" class="sorting">Email
        </th>

        <th aria-label="ACTIONS: activate to sort column ascending" style="" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="data-table" tabindex="0" class="sorting">
          ACTIONS
        </th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
    <%
          @count = 1
       if @leadsHot != nil || @leadsHot != ''
       @leadsHot.each do |lead| %>
        <tr role="row" <% if @count / @count == 0 %>class="gradeA even"<% else %> class="gradeA odd" <% end %>>
          <td class="sorting_1"><%= lead.category.to_s %></td>
          <td><%= lead.fname.to_s %> <%= lead.l_name.to_s %></td>
          <td><%= lead.phone.to_s %></td>
          <td><%= lead.email.to_s %></td>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group m-r-5 m-b-5">
              <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-success">Actions</a>
              <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle">
                <span class="caret"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                <li><a href=/backoffice/sales/view_lead?id=<%= lead.id %>">View</a></li>
                <li><a href="/backoffice/sales/edit_lead?id=<%= lead.id %>">Edit</a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:<%= lead.email %>">Email - <%= lead.email %></a></li>
                <li><a href="/backoffice/process/new_client/create_client?id=<%= lead.id %>">Convert To NEW CLIENT</a></li>
                <li><a href="/backoffice/sales/edit_lead?id=<%= lead.id %>&update=makeDead">Convert To DEAD LEAD</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
    <%
       else
    %><tr><td colspan="7"><h5>No Hot Leads in the system.</h5></td></tr><%
       end
    %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

rails console production results

```
   2.2.1 :004 > Lead.all().where(active: true, hot: true)
  Lead Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `leads`.* FROM `leads` WHERE `leads`.`active` = 1 AND `leads`.`hot` = 1
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Lead id: 1, category: "Cars", patent_status: "none", over_eighteen: "Yes", salute: "Mr", fname: "Middleton", m_initial: "Jacksonmade", l_name: "Longtrowsers", address: "303 Springfield Ave", address1: "Apt D", city: "Lancaster", state: "North Carolina", zip: "97055", phone: "(803) 320-7672", cell_phone: "803-320-7672", fax: "", email: "george@betazedsoftwaresolutionsinc.com", user_id: nil, source: "Call In", lead_source_id: nil, hot: true, comments: "sdgsadfasdg", active: true, created_at: "2015-12-10 08:45:59", updated_at: "2015-12-10 08:45:59">, #<Lead id: 2, category: "Cars", patent_status: "Yes", over_eighteen: "Yes", salute: "Mr.", fname: "Furgo", m_initial: "Robert", l_name: "Man", address: "303 Springfield Ave", address1: "Apt D", city: "Lancaster", state: "North Carolina", zip: "97055", phone: "(803) 320-7672", cell_phone: "803-320-7672", fax: "", email: "billing@betazedsoftwaresolutionsinc.com", user_id: nil, source: "Call In", lead_source_id: nil, hot: true, comments: "asdfasdfasdf", active: true, created_at: "2015-12-10 08:52:21", updated_at: "2015-12-10 08:52:21">]>
```

Comment: Controller and view are not needed to run a query. Could you just show the model(s), your query and the result you get when running the query in `rails console production` (including the database related log output from ActiveRecord)?

Comment: I added the requested information. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, the query does not return nil.

Comment: It was a condition. I had let it slip from my mind that var == nil is not the same as var.nil? so my condition was breaking it not the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually something stupid, if u say it works on dev. Try checking:

1. Connection to database, config
2. Display in view, maybe print debug of object
3. Result of query object, print debug

Temporarily activate debug and check logs for clues or dump the database and try the prod dump carefully in dev

Comment: This actually helped me discover what was wrong with the condition I commented about above. +1 and accepted as the answer! Thanks Mate!

Answer (score 2):

Queries like this `where("hot=0 AND active=1")` are depending on a certain database, because not all databases encode `true` and `false` as `1` or `0`.

Write your queries like this:

```
Lead.where(hot: false, active: true)
```

Comment: Did that but still has the same issue and error. Thanks though I do like that method better :D